# How can I emulate two monitors for the guest OS in Hyper-V

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualization, hyper-v

I have just one big monitor connected to my Windows 8.1 PC and I run Hyper-V with Windows XP as Guest OS.

I would like to emulate two monitors in Hyper V to test the configuration of multiple monitors in Windows XP.

Is there any possibility to emulate a second screen in Hyper-V (Host Windows 8.1 or Windows 10)?

I checked the setting and I didn't find any settings about adding a virtual graphic card or screen.

I guess the emulation in Hyper-V is independent of the Guest OS so if you have an answer for any other Guest OS please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Answered via a Technet post:

> The only way you can get multi monitors with Hyper-V is through RDP,
>   either standard Windows Remote Desktop or the RemoteFX option.
>
> You can use RDP and RemoteFX on the same computer. Deploying Microsoft
>   RemoteFX on a Single Remote Desktop Virtualization Host Server
>   Step-by-Step Guide

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817586(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. This seems to be a lot of work to emulate two screens. I have to study it in detail.